# PHP different time zone

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Javascript:**

```
// now an integer value for easy incrementing
var myTime;

window.onload = function()
{
    getTime();
    setInterval(getTime, 60000);
    setInterval(incrementTime, 1000);
};

function getTime()
{
    $.post('getServerTime.php', function(t)
    {
        myTime = t;
    });

}

function incrementTime()
{
    myTime++;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = new Date(myTime * 1000);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="demo">0</div>
```

I am in Asia but I use below time zone. When I pass the result to html, it still display my Asia's time.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

echo time();
?>
```

Comment: *"When I pass the result to html"* - What "html" is that? and js for that matter that you tagged as. Where's your server located? Asia maybe?

Comment: @Fred-ii- updated

Comment: bunch of answers below there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at date_default_timezone_get() and ini_set(date.timezone) as seen here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php
and here:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone

Answer (score 0):

Check example at the [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Answer (score 0):

**try it**

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Romania/Bucharest');
echo date('D M d Y H:i:s');
exit();
?>
```

---

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

  $.get( "get_date.php", function(data) {
    alert(data);
  });
```

Comment: Even though you set time zone to Romania/Bucharest, i guess it will still show the current time zone's date time. Must be something to do with php.ini configuration file :/